# JavaScript: Code moves too fast, should I write a Promise?

Tags: javascript, asynchronous, promise, settimeout

I'm trying to make my web app a little more user friendly, and instead of instantly removing an element I want it to fade away before actually being removed. The problem is my code is running too quickly. While I understand everything is working correctly, I need it to wait for the element to "disappear" before actually being removed. Is this a good example of when to use a `Promise` or should I use `setTimeout()`?

### Code Overview

```
check if variables exist
if button is clicked change element opacity (transition: opacity 1s;)
then call deletePostPromise()
then remove the element from the dom
```

As you can see, I'm even writing my pseudocode as a promise, `then.. then..`.

Specifically, start at `row.style.opacity = '0';`

```
if (displayPostWrapper && submitPostBtn) {
  displayPostWrapper.addEventListener('click', e => {
    if (e.target && e.target.nodeName == 'BUTTON') {
      e.preventDefault();

      const {  parentElement } = e.target;
      const row    = parentElement.parentElement.parentElement;
      const form   = parentElement;
      const postID = parentElement.childNodes[3].value;;

      row.style.opacity = '0';

      deletePostPromise('http://localhost/mouthblog/ajax/delete_post.ajax.php', `id=${postID}`)
        .then(() => {
          row.remove();
        });

      // row.remove();
    } // if
  }); // click event
```

### EDIT

### JS

```
const deletePostPromise = (url, postID) => {
  return new Promise((resolve, reject) => {
    const xhr = new XMLHttpRequest();

    xhr.open('POST', url, true);

    xhr.onload = () => {
      if (xhr.status == 200) {
        console.log('if (xhr.status == 200)');
        resolve();
      } else {
        reject(xhr.statusText);
      }
    };

    xhr.onerror = () => {
      reject(xhr.statusText);
    };

    xhr.setRequestHeader('Content-type', 'application/x-www-form-urlencoded');
    xhr.send(postID);
  });
}

if (displayPostWrapper && submitPostBtn) {
  displayPostWrapper.addEventListener('click', e => {
    if (e.target && e.target.nodeName == 'BUTTON') {
      e.preventDefault();

      const { parentElement } = e.target;
      const row               = parentElement.parentElement.parentElement;
      const form              = parentElement;
      const postID            = parentElement.childNodes[3].value;;

      row.style.opacity = '0';

      deletePostPromise('http://localhost/mouthblog/ajax/delete_post.ajax.php', `id=${postID}`);

      row.addEventListener("transitionend", function(event) {
        // alert('Done!');
        row.remove();
      }, false);
    } // if
  }); // click event
```

### CSS

```
.row {
      opacity: 1;
      transition: opacity 5s;
    }
```

Comment: Using promises without `setTimeout` here is pretty pointless. If you want to wait 1s, use a timeout.

Comment: Why not do the ajax request immediately as well? Just don't remove the element from the DOM before the second has elapsed.

Comment: @jfriend00 You mean just a simple `if` statement?

Comment: @Bergi I don't think I understand, `using promises without setTimeout is pointless`? I get the second part.

Comment: You were asking whether you would use either promises *or* `setTimeout`. I meant to say that you'd use both.

Comment: No.  Not an `if`.  See my answer for details.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can set a [listener using the `transitionend` event](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/Events/transitionend) that will tell you when the opacity transition has completed and then you can remove the element then.

```
row.addEventListener("transitionend", function(event) {
  console.log("transition completed, removing row");
  row.remove();
}, false);
```

You would add this listener right before you change the opacity which triggers the start of the fadeout.

Here's a simple working example that you can run to see it work.

```js
function log(msg) {
    let div = document.createElement("div");
    div.innerHTML = msg;
    document.getElementById("log").appendChild(div);
}

document.getElementById("run").addEventListener("click", function() {
    document.getElementById("test").style.opacity = 0;
});

let test = document.getElementById("test");

test.addEventListener("transitionend", function(e) {
    log(`transitionend for ${e.propertyName}, removing DOM element`)
    test.remove();
});
```

```css
.fade {
   opacity: 1;
   transition: opacity 2s;
}
```

```html
<button id="run">
Start Animation
</button>
<div class="fade" id="test">
Some content that will fade out
</div>
<div id="log">

</div>
```

Comment: Probably the neatest thing I will learn today, appreciate it.

Comment: So I wrote my own listener and I thought it was working. Just made it disappear but the `row.remove()` was never called. So I copy/pasted yours, and now it's being immediately removed again instead of "fading" away. What gives?

Comment: @BrandonBenefield - I'd have to see the whole context of the actual code you're using to be able to see what needs fixing.

Comment: True, sorry about that. I'll edit my question. If you'd like to give it a look over I would appreciate it. What else do you need, just the CSS for the row correct?

Comment: @BrandonBenefield - What does `deletePostPromise()` do?  Which browser are you running it in? Do you have any other CSS transitions going on that element?

Comment: @BrandonBenefield - Here's a simple, working example: https://jsfiddle.net/jfriend00/4oa886wk/

Comment: I'm using chrome, I've updated the EDIT section of my JS to show what `deletePostPromise()` does, it's just your run of the mill promise that sends a form to a URL and the php script there queries the DB and removes the post with the ID that is sent with AJAX.

Comment: As you can see from the working example in my answer, the concept as I've shown it works fine.  If it is not working for you, you'd have to do some debugging to try to figure out what is going on.  Do you have the appropriate CSS transtion property set for your `row` object?  That's what is required to trigger both the CSS animation and the `transitionend` event.  See the example in my answer.

Comment: Yea the example works, and it's sort of working on my project. But it's not waiting for the transition to end, which is the point of 'transitionend'. If I set an `alert()` and kee the `alert` open during the `transition` it will do everything correctly. But if I remove the `alert()` from my `transitionend` handler OR if I click `okay` to remove the `alert` then it just happens instantly. Weird stuff. If you look in my question at the bottom I've inserted the css for `.row` which corresponds with my JS variable `row`. I wonder if dynamically inserting elements causes an error here.

Comment: @BrandonBenefield - FYI, never use `alert()` when debugging asynchronous operations because the `alert()` messes with the timing.  Use `console.log()` to output debug msgs and look at them in the debug console.

Comment: @BrandonBenefield - It sounds like you may have some other transition going too that triggers your `transitionend` event too soon.  As you can see in my example, you can examine `event.propertyName` in the `transitionend` event handler to see what is trigger it.  It's possible it's getting triggered too soon by some other transition.  You can add this to your event handler: `console.log(\`transitionend for ${event.propertyName}\`)`.  If you find other transitions are trigger it also, then you can do `if (event.propertyName === "opacity") ...`

Comment: Thanks for the tip. Using your jsfiddle, more specifically where you logged the `e.propertyName`, I'm getting 5 different properties that are being logged. None of which are for opacity either. `box-shadow, border-bottom-color, background-color, border-top-color, border-left-color`. Which is odd because I haven't set any of these for `.row`. So if `opacity` isn't even being triggered then... who knows.

Comment: I'm going to start a new question instead of filling this one up with a different topic. I appreciate your time and sending me in the right direction, thank you!

Comment: @BrandonBenefield - Yeah, now it appears to be about your HTML and CSS and why you're not getting the right transition event.  Your new question will need to show that.